# Lua table initialization - what is incorrect here

Tags: lua, initialization, lua-table

I am trying to initialize and print a table.  It just isnt working.  Any idea what is wrong with this code?

```
--!/usr/bin/env lua


local retv = {}
retv["test"] = 1000

for k,v in ipairs(retv) do
    print (k,v)
end
```

It prints nothing.  I am sure I am missing something very basic but I cant figure this out.

Comment: Curious start of file. Should that be the Unix shebang? `#!/usr/bin/env lua`

Comment: Oh sorry that is just a cut and paste error from my terminal session - missed out the #

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two forms of the `for`-loop in Lua:
The numeric and the generic for-loop.

`ipairs(t)` is an iterator constructor returning up to three arguments suitable for the generic for, allowing you to iterate over the initial sequence (indices 1,2,3,...) in order.
Possible implementations:

```
function ipairs(t)
  local i = 0
  return function()
    i = i + 1
    if t[i] ~= nil then
      return i, t[i]
    end
  end
end
```

```
local function ipairs_helper(t, i)
  i = i + 1
  if t[i] ~= nil then
    return i, t[i]
  end
end
function ipairs(t)
  return ipairs_helper, t, 0
end
```

As you can see, that will never return your entry with key `"test"`.

What you want instead, is `pairs(t)`, which is equivalent to `next, t`.
That will iterate all elements.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `pairs` instead of `ipairs`. `pairs` iterates over all keys, `ipairs` only iterates over [keys that form a sequence of integers starting from 1 without gaps](http://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.5.html). (Whether these keys are stored in the array or the hash part of the table is an implementation detail and may change during the lifetime of the table.)

For example, `ipairs({'a', 'b', nil, 'c'})` iterates over keys 1 and 2, stopping at (and not including) 3, as that key is missing from the table.

Comment: The terminology is from [Lua FAQ](http://www.luafaq.org/#T1.10): "ipairs(t) goes over the array part".

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect that.